# How do you make hunger go away in minecraft without monsters spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried using `/gamemode doMobSpawning false`, but it said it was invalid. What do I do?

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe if you play on "Peaceful" difficulty, no hostile mobs will spawn. Pigs and sheep etc. will still spawn however. Additionally, while you can't die of starvation in peaceful, you still can lose health if you don't eat regularly enough.

Comment: Additionally, `doMobSpawning` is not a gamemode - which is why that command didn't work. Gamemode only has 3 commands `0`, `1`, and `2`, which I believe is Creative, Survival, and Adventure.

Comment: As @Ben said, doMobSpawning is not a gamemode. It is actually a gamerule. Just replace "gamemode" with "gamerule".

Answer (score 5):

To remove all mobs (other than player-placed ones, such as armor stands), simply use the mob spawning gamerule.
<s>I don't know why Minecraft seems to be spitting out errors, but what you've typed seems to be correct. Are you perhaps using a version of Minecraft prior to 1.4.2?</s>

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

If you do not want to have to worry about hunger, simply have a command block on loop running this command:

```
/effect @a minecraft:saturation 2 10
```

---

Alternatively, peaceful difficulty does the above, only that it still allows peaceful (animals) to spawn.

```
/difficulty 0
```

Comment: He was using /gamemode, instead of /gamerule.

Comment: @TheVoidChaos Right. I'm blind. :P

Answer (score 0):

As shown above by @TheVoidChaos and @aytimothy, you are using `/gamemode` instead of `/gamerule`.  Use `/gamerule`.

Answer (score -2):

Turn off Mobs Option for Creative Mode. Put down a command block, enter /gamerule doMobSpawning false, and turn it on with a lever.

Comment: Or you could just type it into the chat box.